# Transformation of recursive defined polynomial to reverse coefficient order?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, transformation, recursion

Lets define a recursive polynomial sequence by

\begin{align}
A_0(x) &= 1 \\
A_n(x) &= x \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k \cdot A_{n-k}(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k x^k
\end{align}

Is there a way to transform this recursive definition in a way such that I get a polynomial with reversed coefficient order of polynomial $A_n(x)$ such that:

\begin{align}
B_0(x) &= 1 \\
B_n(x) &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^n b_k x^k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{k} x^{n-k+1} = \quad \text{recursive definition of } B_n(x) \text{ ?}
\end{align}

I already tried intuitively

\begin{align}
B_0(x) &= 1 \\
B_n(x) &= x \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k B_{k-1}(x)
\end{align}

but that didn't work out.

**Edit 1:** with Professor's Vector answer I tried

\begin{align}
A(x) &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k x^k \\
A(x^{-1}) &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k x^{-k} \\
x^{n+1} A(x^{-1}) &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k x^{n-k+1} = B_n(x) \\
A_n(x) &= x \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k A_{n-k}(x) \\
x^{n+1}A_n(x) &= x \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k x^{n+1} A_{n-k}(x) \\
x^{n+1}A_n(x^{-1}) &= x^{-1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k x^{-n-1} A_{n-k}(x^{-1}) \\
x^{n+1}A_n(x^{-1}) &= x^{-1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k x^{-2n+k-2} x^{n-k+1} A_{n-k}(x^{-1}) \\
x^{n+1}A_n(x^{-1}) &= x^{-2n-3} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k x^{k} x^{n-k+1} A_{n-k}(x^{-1}) \\
B_n(x) &= x^{-2n-3} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k x^{k} B_{n-k}(x) \\
\end{align}

but this is obvious wrong. Maybe mistake of myself?

Comment: You could use $B_n(x)=x^n\,A_n(x^{-1}).$

Comment: If I do this, then I get: $B_n(x) = x \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} g(k) x^{k-2(n+1)} B_{n-k}(x)$. But this is not working, too.

Comment: I edited my post and tried it your way. But still, it did not work out.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many errors in your calculation to point them out one by one. You have to start from $$A_n(x) = x \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \, A_{n-k}(x).$$
Then
$$A_n(x^{-1}) = x^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \, A_{n-k}(x^{-1})$$
$$x^nA_n(x^{-1}) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \, x^{n-1}A_{n-k}(x^{-1})=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \, x^{k-1}x^{n-k}A_{n-k}(x^{-1}).$$
With $B_n(x)=x^nA_n(x^{-1}),$ this is
$$B_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \, x^{k-1}B_{n-k}(x).$$